# Trying to clone or pull Git from GitHub but no error

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I tried to clone or pull repository from GitHub but nothing happened and also no error :(

```
git clone https://github.com/test/test.git test
```

Cloning into 'test'...

after this message nothing else. Any idea where I can check the error log? because same command is working on different server but not on Amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a firewall issue? The Git protocol listens on port 9418.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol